# Using @ConditionalOnProperty with regex prefix patterns spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

I have a configuration class in my spring boot application which I want to enable only if certain properties in my `application.properties` file matches it.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "^sites\\[.*\\].*", name = "^prefix.*")
public class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public TestManager getTestManager() {
        System.out.println("Created TestManager"); //just for debugging purposes
        return new TestManager();
    }
}
```

In my `application.properties` file I have a set of properties as below:

```
sites[0].id=site1
sites[0].name=site1 name
sites[0].datasource.url=
sites[0].datasource.user=

sites[1].id=site2
sites[1].name=site2 name
sites[1].datasource.url=
sites[1].datasource.user=
.
.
site[n].... so on
```

I want to create my `TestManager` bean only if these properties are present. When I try to have regex pattern on my prefix attribute it's not working out. What is the correct way of handling such situations? Is there any better approach for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve the desired result by creating a custom `Condition` class and adding the logic to iterate through each of my `application.properties` file properties and see if it matches the regex pattern or not.

```
public class CustomCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        Optional<String> sitesProperty  = ((AbstractEnvironment)context.getEnvironment()).getPropertySources().stream()
                .filter(propertySource -> propertySource instanceof EnumerablePropertySource)
                .map(propertySource -> (EnumerablePropertySource) propertySource)
                .flatMap(propertySource -> Arrays.stream(propertySource.getPropertyNames()))
                .distinct()
                .filter(propertyName -> propertyName.matches("^sites\\S\\d\\S.*"))
                .findAny();

        return sitesProperty.isPresent();
    }
}
```